# Extracting *relevant* image from a web-page

Tags: html, parsing, image-extraction

I have a couple of twitter-powered news aggregation website. I have been planning to add images from articles that I find on twitter.

If I download the page and extract image using `<img>` tag, I get a bunch of images; not all of them relevant to the article. For example, images of button, icons, ads etc are captured. How do I extract the image accompanying the article? I know there is a solution -- Facebook link sharer does this pretty well.

Mithun

Duplicate of : [How to find and extract "main" image in website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268386/how-to-find-and-extract-main-image-in-website)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's been a long time. But this may help next time.

You can use this API https://urlmeta.org/

It's very simple to use and result is the best we need.

example for using API:

```
<?php
$url = "http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/business/india-business/Raghuram-Rajan-not-fit-to-be-RBI-Governor-Subramanian-Swamy/articleshow/52236298.cms";

$result = file_get_contents('https://api.urlmeta.org/?url='.$url);
$array = json_decode($result,1);
print_r($array['meta']['image']);

?>
```

And that's the result you needed.

Comment: urlmeta.org is pretty cool. Works for almost all ecommerce product pages.

Answer (score 8):

Download all images from the page, 
blacklist all images coming from an ad server.
then find some heuristic which will get you the correct image...

I think something like:

- Biggest resolution += 5pts
- Biggest filesize += 10 pts
- Jpeg += 2 pts

then take the image with the most points and throw the rest away

Probably works for majority of sites.

(Would require some fiddling with the heuristics though)

Comment: This is the classic approach and thank you for putting it down here. I was a bit hesitant to go down this path because I was not sure how long this will take. Like you said, it will probably work great after some tuning. Couple more factores that I found elsewhere are: 1] the path of the image. 2] images whose width and height are specified

Answer (score 3):

I kind of came-up with a solution that is a bit hacky but works for me. Here is what I do to get thumbnails.

1. Say the headline of the page I find is "this is a headline"
2. I use this as a query to the Google Image API and then extract the first thumbnail I find.

It actually works quite well for a majority of the cases. Check it out for yourself http://cricketfresh.in

Mithun

ps: I think this is a good answer. Will give credit to someone who comes with a more elegant answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that Facebook has a link extractor for the various sites it supports. Something like id="content" -> img (1st).

Guess I am wrong. Seems that Facebook uses the [Open Graph Protocol](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph) to define which image (og:image) and which metadata to use.

Comment: Well OGP is something Facebook is pushing so that they can extract meta-data accurately. Unfortunately, a large number of website do not follow this standard.