# How to find and extract "main" image in website

Tags: java, html

I need help tackling a problem. I need a program which, given a site, finds and extracts the "main" picture, i.e. the one which represents the site. (To say it is the *biggest* or the *first* picture is sometimes but not always true).

How should I approach this? Are there any libraries that could help me with this?
Thanks!

Comment: [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**OPTION 1**

You could checkout [Goose](https://github.com/GravityLabs/goose). It does something similar to what Pocket and Readability does, i.e. try to extract the main article from a given webpage using a set of heuristics. It can apparently also extract the main image from that article, but it is a bit of a hit and miss, so 60% of the time it works everytime.

It used to be a Java project but rewritten to Scala.

From the readme

> Goose will try to extract the following information:
>
> - Main text of an article
> - **Main image of article**
> - Any Youtube/Vimeo movies embedded in article
> - Meta Description
> - Meta tags
> - Publish Date

Try it here: http://jimplush.com/blog/goose

---

**OPTION 2**

You could use a Java wrapper (e.g. [GhostDriver](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver)) for running a headless browser, like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). Then, fetch the website and find the `img` element with the largest dimensions. [This GhostDriver test case](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/blob/master/test/java/src/test/java/ghostdriver/ElementQueryingTest.java) shows how to query the DOM for elements and get it's renderd size.

---

**OPTION 3**

Use a library like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) that helps you parse HTML. Then get the value from the `src` attribute from all `img` tags. Request each URL you find for an image and measure their sizes. The one with the biggest dimensions is likely to be the website's main image.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is, that it says, "Goose is meant to work with individual articles, not homepages", which is kind of the opposite of what I need.

Comment: @nodwj I have updated my answer with two new suggestions for possible approaches.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution would be to extract the meta tags for social media sharing first, if they are present, you are lucky otherwise you stil can try the other solutions.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/image.jpg"/>
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://www.example.com/image.jpg">
<meta itemprop="image" content="http://www.example.com/image.jpg">
```

If you are yousing JSOUP the code would be like that:

```
    String imageUrlOpenGraph = document.select("meta[property=og:image]").stream()
            .findFirst()
            .map(doc -> doc.attr("content").trim())
            .orElse(null);

    String imageUrlTwitter = document.select("meta[name=twitter:image]").stream()
                .findFirst()
                .map(doc -> doc.attr("content").trim())
                .orElse(null);

    String imageUrlGooglePlus = document.select("meta[itemprop=image]").stream()
                .findFirst()
                .map(doc -> doc.attr("content").trim())
                .orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a service like [embedly](http://embed.ly/). Among a lot of other information they allow you to extract the main image of any page. Works particularly well for articles. You can try it [here](http://embed.ly/extract).

Answer (score 0):

You need artificial intelligence to do so, Computer Vision namely.
It too big to fit in an answer. [This link might help](https://www.udacity.com/course/cs271)

If you are a mathematician with experience of Probability and Bayes rule, then you can just take the unit called **Image Processing and Computer Vision**.

If you are looking for available software you want to use [check this out...](http://sourceforge.net/projects/imgrecognition/)

[This stackoverflow thread might help...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14874971/are-there-any-free-image-recognition-apis-out-there)

There's this software called [moodstocks](http://www.moodstocks.com/) which might help.

Comment: Is there a heuristic to do it more simply? (even with some cost of accuracy?)

Comment: no mate, accept the fact. How on earth do you think can you detect images without intelligence?

Comment: Let me make my question more clear: I need help creating that so called intelligence (AI), and my goal is a rather simple and short algorithm even if not 100% accurate.

Answer (score 0):

[ImageResolver](https://github.com/mauricesvay/ImageResolver) can do that for you without the need of server side interaction, except for a small proxy script.